# Problem compiling Tikz automaton library example

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, automata

This doesn't compile for me (adapted from p.521 of the Tikz manual, v3.0.0):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
\node[state,initial] (q_0) {$q_0$};
\node[state] (q_1) [above right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
\node[state] (q_2) [below right=of q_0] {$q_2$};
\node[state,accepting](q_3) [below right=of q_1] {$q_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Tikz doesn't seem to recognize `on grid` or the `of` operator. I was previously using Tikz 2.1 so I went through a [laborious manual upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543237/unsuccessful-upgrade-from-tex-live-from-2013-to-2014-on-ubuntu-14-04) to TeXLive 2014 so that I could pull version 3.0.0 into my Ubuntu system.

Unfortunately I'm getting exactly the same error, so I must be missing something really quite silly. Help?

Comment: Try with `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` and take a look at [why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

Comment: I think you need to at least add \usetikzlibrary{positioning} for the above right = of option. Not sure about on grid, though. And I'm on mobile at the moment.

Comment: Ok, that does it. Please add as an answer. (Shame the examples aren't more self-contained!)

Comment: @Ignasi Thanks, replaced 'minimal' by 'article' in the question.

Comment: @Roly In general, as you are reading Tikz manual, you need to remember to include the library you are currently reading about. I burned my fingers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include `positioning` library (section 17.5.3 Advanced Placement Options) which is needed when `of` parts are used in node placement specifications.